# How to get firebase ref from known child value

Tags: android, firebase

Maybe a confusing title, but I'll try to explain as best as I can.
When creating a certain fragment, I want to load the value of a "scriptURL" child in firebase into a TextView field.
As the fragment is created the value of a "sibling" of the "scriptURL" child is carried into the fragment by args.

My firebase structure is like this:

```
root
-scripts
--UID
---scripttitle:"title"
---scripturl:"url"
--UID
---scripttitle:"title"
---scripturl:"url"
```

As the fragment is loaded I have the value of "scripttitle" in a string.
I want to use this to get the corresponding scripturl, but cant figure out how to do that.

The code of my fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        String clickedScript = args.getString("clickedScript", null);
        RelativeLayout llLayout    = (RelativeLayout)    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_script_details, container, false);
        final TextView clicked = (TextView)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.scriptTitle);
        final TextView url = (TextView)llLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        clicked.setText(clickedScript);

        Firebase ref = new Firebase("http://theatre-assistant.firebaseio.com/scripts").child(clickedScript);
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                url.setText((String) snapshot.child("scripturl").getValue());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });




        return llLayout;
    }
```

This way the text field ends up blank. I believe my firebase ref is way off, but that was the only thing I could think of.
Hope this makes some sense, and that somebody can point me in the right direction to make this work.
I am new to this, so I may be way off in my thinking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load the script like this:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("http://theatre-assistant.firebaseio.com/scripts")
                      .child(clickedScript);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

The `child()` method references a child whose key is the value of `clickedScript`. Such a child does not exist.

Instead you are looking to execute a query:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("http://theatre-assistant.firebaseio.com/scripts");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("scripttitle").equalTo(clickedScript);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
      url.setText((String) child.child("scripturl").getValue());
    }
  }
```

That for loop is necessary since a query can match any number of children, so it returns a list. Even when there's only one matching child (like you expect), it will return a list of length one.

Aside from that, the querying is covered in the [Firebase guide on querying data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That did it! I had a feeling it was something along those lines, but couldn't get my head around it.

Comment: It helps a ton if you next time try to isolate the code that has the problem. This problem for example is unrelated to Android, which means that you'd have the same problem in a (much simpler) Java app. Isolating the problem makes it more likely that you'll find the problem yourself *and* if you don't, it'll make is easier for others to spot the problem (since they have fewer things to consider).

Comment: A note on your data structure: you seem to want `scripttitle` values to be unique. In that case you're probably better of storing them as `/scripts/$scripttitle/scripturl`. With that structure your original code would've worked, you're guaranteed that script titles are unique and it's more scalable (since you can directly address the child node, instead of firing a potentially expensive query).

Comment: Yes, I considered that, but I was thinking in case more than one theatre group was working on the same play, there would possibly be more than one entry with the same name. And now that I am writing this I see that problem still exists.. So scripttitle values may not be unique. I need to rethink this..